# Dart sort list of symbols (strings) by nth element in each string

Tags: list, dart, sorting

I have this list of strings (`List<String>`):

```
LAT-3-45.3256435634
LNG-2-43.542352345654
LAT-1-45.32564356345
LNG-4-43.542352345654
LAT-1-45.325643563456
LNG-2-43.54235234565
LAT-3-45.325643563456
LNG-5-4.5423523456
etc etc.
```

I want to sort them by integer value (first number, second element after LAT or LNG, between minuses).

Desired result:

```
LAT-1-45.32564356345
LNG-1-43.54235234546654
LAT-2-45.325643563984
LNG-2-43.542352345654
LAT-3-45.32564356346756
LNG-3-4.5423523456676
LAT-4-45.325646753563456
LNG-4-4.54765623523456
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What part do you need help with?  Parsing the string?  Sorting it once you have the data structure? Displaying the result?

Comment: Just sort by numbers (ints; here on example:  3,4 ,5 2, 5)/ I want to sort this List<string> by second "element" (int number)

Comment: @PrertoQuebas Could you add an example that shows how how you want it to get sorted, to your question?

Comment: Yes of course. I have added "desired results". Thanks for help!

Comment: @PrertoQuebas Multiple numbers in your "Desired result" are not represented in your input. Please make so you have an example of inputs and then show the expected result with that input. Otherwise it is very hard to know if our solution is actually solving your problem.

Comment: You are right, these are just number for example purposes. Maybe input example is not the best , but the idea of the problem is not so complicated ;) I want to sort all strings by first (integer) number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a compare method to the `sort()` method on `List`. This method is called for each comparison. In this case, we need to parse each `String` in the comparison so we can compare the int value.

This can be done by something like the following. I have added the logic that if two `int` values are equal, we instead sort based on the `LAT` and `LNG` text:

```dart
  input.sort((a, b) {
    List<String> partsA = a.split('-');
    List<String> partsB = b.split('-');
    int valueA = int.parse(partsA[1]);
    int valueB = int.parse(partsB[1]);

    int compare = valueA.compareTo(valueB);
    return compare != 0 ? compare : partsA[0].compareTo(partsB[0]);
  });
```

An example of usage can be seen in this full test program:

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> input = [
    'LAT-1-45.32564356345',
    'LNG-1-43.54235234546654',
    'LAT-2-45.325643563984',
    'LNG-2-43.542352345654',
    'LAT-3-45.32564356346756',
    'LNG-3-4.5423523456676',
    'LAT-4-45.325646753563456',
    'LNG-4-4.54765623523456',
  ]..shuffle(); // <-- Shuffle to simulate the list are coming in random order

  input.forEach(print);
  // LAT-1-45.32564356345
  // LAT-4-45.325646753563456
  // LNG-1-43.54235234546654
  // LAT-2-45.325643563984
  // LAT-3-45.32564356346756
  // LNG-3-4.5423523456676
  // LNG-4-4.54765623523456
  // LNG-2-43.542352345654
  print('-----------------------');

  input.sort((a, b) {
    List<String> partsA = a.split('-');
    List<String> partsB = b.split('-');
    int valueA = int.parse(partsA[1]);
    int valueB = int.parse(partsB[1]);

    int compare = valueA.compareTo(valueB);
    return compare != 0 ? compare : partsA[0].compareTo(partsB[0]);
  });
  
  input.forEach(print);
  // LAT-1-45.32564356345
  // LNG-1-43.54235234546654
  // LAT-2-45.325643563984
  // LNG-2-43.542352345654
  // LAT-3-45.32564356346756
  // LNG-3-4.5423523456676
  // LAT-4-45.325646753563456
  // LNG-4-4.54765623523456
}
```

Comment: I will test code soon, but it looks great! Many thanks!